# Can we set cursor as a session variable?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I tried to set a cursor as a session variable looks like it is not working.

Anyone has idea about it ??

My Code:

```
 Meteor.call('apiresult',function(e,result)
    {                                               
    console.log(result);
    Session.set("object",result)                                                                                                        
    }); 

//getting variable
 var abc=Session.get("object");
return abc.skimlinksProductAPI.numFound;
```

looks like it's not working

Comment: Method results and Session vars should be EJSON-compatible types. Read about EJSON here: http://docs.meteor.com/#ejson

Comment: my result is JSON type still why it's not working

Comment: Cursors are not EJSON-able. The only types that EJSON supports by default are primitives (strings, booleans, numbers), basic non-typed object literals, arrays, and the few typed objects that the Meteor team has made EJSON compatible - `Date`, binary types like `Uint8Array`, and `Meteor.Collection.ObjectID`. Other types like cursors, `HTMLElement`s, jQuery objects, etc are not EJSON-able, so they cannot be used as arguments/return values for methods, or be stored in Session vars. They will instead be sent as basic JSON objects without any type information (prototype, constructor, methods)

Comment: @sasikanth The Cursor does not have an EJSON type so it can't be converted to EJSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cursors *can* actually be stored in `Session`... sometimes. open the [leaderboard app](http://leaderboard.meteor.com/) and try this in the browser console:

> > Session.set('mycursor', Players.find());
>   undefined
>   > Session.get('mycursor')
>   LocalCollection.Cursor {collection: LocalCollection, selector_f: function, sort_f: null, skip: undefined, limit: undefined…}
>   > Session.get('mycursor').fetch()
>   [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Now download the [code of the leaderboard example app](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/examples/leaderboard), use the latest Meteor, and do the same thing in the browser console. You might get:

[image]

The moral of the story seems to be, don't store cursors in session variables. Store [the Minimongo selector and options](http://docs.meteor.com/#find) (`sort`, `fields` etc.) instead as objects.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting thought. It would not be required though, because a cursor is already reactive. You can store the cursor in an ordinary variable.

One thing to point out though is you can't send cursors down using `Meteor.call`, you can send down javascript objects or specify your own EJSON but you couldn't do this with cursors.

So you can store cursors in global variables if you do the .find() locally, but you cant do it on the server then transfer the cursor using Meteor.call

You can use a publish/subscribe function for this instead.