# How to change the value of a variable on click in meteor

Tags: meteor

In my meteor app I need to load an array of items corresponding to the item clicked.As I'm new to meteor, I'm held up here.Here is my code.

```
Template.templatename.events({
'click .showdiv' : function()
{
  Template.templatename.vname = function () {
  return Db.find();
  }
}
```

Can I set the variable vname dynamically by this code ? This is not working for me.

Comment: How exactly is it "not working"?

Comment: I'm rendering the variable vname in my template and its not getting displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the notion of reactivity.  A [reactive data source](http://docs.meteor.com/#reactivity) will cause any functions which depend on it (including helpers) to rerun when its value is changed, which seems to be the behavior you're looking for here.  Instead, you're rewriting the helper function itself every time an item is clicked, which kind of defeats the object of Meteor's reactive data model.  Session variables could help:

```
Template.templatename.events({
    'click .showdiv' : function() {
        Session.set('vname', Db.find());
    }
});

Template.templatename.vname = function () {
    return Session.get('vname');
}
```

If you use an `{{#each vname}}` block in the `templatename` template, it will automatically update with the results of the `Db.find()` query when a `.showdiv` is clicked.  If all you want to do is show the result of that query regardless of whether a click has been registered it would be as simple as:

```
Template.templatename.vname = function () {
    return Db.find();
}
```

Note that it's still not clear exactly what data you're trying to populate here since the query will return a cursor (which is fine, but you need to loop through it using `{{#each ...}}` - use `findOne` if you only want one item), and its contents aren't going to depend on anything intrinsic to the click event (like which `.showdiv` you clicked).  In the former example it will however fail to show anything until the first click (after which you would have to reset with `Session.set('vname', null)` to stop it showing anything again).

Comment: The scenario is like, I have a list of users and on clicking a user I need to display some data related to the user from another collection in a popup which is defined as another template.

Comment: Regarding `Session.set('vname', Db.find());` - there are [some problems with setting cursors as Session variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822469/can-we-set-cursor-as-a-session-variable/). What is your take on that?

Comment: Yes, agreed, it's a flimsy solution and not at all necessary in this example when you could just return the cursor itself and avoid the use of Session variables altogether.  The alternative would be to `fetch` the results and store them in a Session variable, but that's clearly not optimal here.